# Windows 10 Bluetooth Gatt Client ValueChanged issue

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app, gatt

I'm having an issue with Bluetooth Gatt characteristic reading at the moment. I was trying to run the code with my own custom profile

```
thermometerCharacteristic.ValueChanged += temperatureMeasurementChanged;
```

It causes this exception

An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range.

My function arguments looks like this

```
void temperatureMeasurementChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
```

This code resembles the sample to retrieve Bluetooth LE data on MSDN. Any ideas on what could cause this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
Check for thermometerCharacteristic.CharacteristicProperties == (GattCharacteristicProperties.Read | GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify)
```

before subscribing:

```
     if (characteristic.CharacteristicProperties == (GattCharacteristicProperties.Read | GattCharacteristicProperties.Notify))
        {
            characteristic.ValueChanged += Characteristic_ValueChanged;

            GattCommunicationStatus status =
                       await characteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(
                       CHARACTERISTIC_NOTIFICATION_TYPE);
        }
```